# What is valid check for LV storage pool in j2 template with ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to define LV storage pools using ansible as follows.  I'm struggling with how to check which is used in the **.xml.j2** file during definition.

Can anyone suggest how to do so and define the required pool, production in this example?

I was thinking of somehow using a reference to `'name: "{{ production_storage_pool }}"'` from the play? Both pools are on the same host so no host check can be done.

```
name: Define Production Storage Pool
  virt_pool:
    command: define
    name: "{{ production_storage_pool }}"
    xml: "{{ lookup('template', '../templates/pool.xml.j2') }}"


    <pool type='logical'>
    {% if HOW TO CHECK FOR "{{ staging_storage_pool }}" %}
      <name>{{ staging_storage_pool }}</name>
      <source>
        <device path='{{ staging_disk }}'/>
        <name>{{ staging_volgroup }}</name>
        <format type='lvm2'/>
      </source>
      <target>
        <path>/dev/{{ staging_volgroup }}</path>
      </target>
    {% elif HOW TO CHECK FOR "{{ production_storage_pool }}" %}
      <name>{{ production_storage_pool }}</name>
      <source>
        <device path='{{ production_disk }}'/>
        <name>{{ production_volgroup }}</name>
        <format type='lvm2'/>
      </source>
       <target>
        <path>/dev/{{ production_volgroup }}</path>
       </target>
    {% endif % }
    </pool>
```

I am currently using two separate files but I'd like just one with a check etc.

Comment: Hi mickt, welcome to SO. I don't understand your question; are you asking how `if` statements work in jinja2? What is `HOW TO CHECK FOR` in your question?

Comment: Hi, sorry for lack of clarity.  In this example I need a check that will determine if the staging or production configuration is to be used.  As both will apply to the same host, I can't use a host check.  Is it possible to determine this based on the play that is bring run?

Comment: The answer is extraordinarily specific to your situation; do the staging or production servers have different subnets, hostnames, or some other variable?

Comment: Both production and staging storage pools will be on the same servers. I'm currently using two files, one for each; it's more a nice to have if I could use one file. I was hoping maybe the ansible play could be referenced but this may not be possible.

Comment: They will use different VLANs but currently sharing the one as others not yet available. Both VLANS again on all servers etc. Unsure  if it helps in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: I defined production_pool & staging_pool variables in each playbook and used 'is defined' check in j2 template.

```
vars:
  production_pool:

- debug: var=staging_pool

- debug: var=production_pool

name: Define Production Storage Pool
  virt_pool:
    command: define
    name: "{{ production_storage_pool }}"
    xml: "{{ lookup('template', '../templates/pool.xml.j2') }}"


<pool type='logical'>
{% if staging_pool is defined %}
  <name>{{ staging_storage_pool }}</name>
  <source>
    <device path='{{ staging_disk }}'/>
    <name>{{ staging_volgroup }}</name>
    <format type='lvm2'/>
  </source>
  <target>
    <path>/dev/'{{ staging_volgroup }}'</path>
  </target>
{% elif production_pool is defined %}
  <name>{{ production_storage_pool }}</name>
  <source>
    <device path='{{ production_disk }}'/>
    <name>{{ production_volgroup }}</name>
    <format type='lvm2'/>
  </source>
   <target>
    <path>/dev/'{{ production_volgroup }}'</path>
   </target>
{% endif % }
</pool>


TASK [debug]
ok: [hostname] => {
    "staging_pool": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [debug]
ok: [hostname] => {
   "production_pool": null
}
```